# Splitting strings into number and string (with missings)

Tags: r, regex, string, tidyverse

I am trying to separate numbers and characters in a column of strings. So far I have been using `tidyr::separate` for doing this, but am encountering errors for "unusual" cases.

Suppose I have the following data

```
df <- data.frame(c1 = c("5.5K", "2M", "3.1", "M"))
```

And I want to obtain a data frame with columns

```
data.frame(c2 = c("5.5", "2", "3.1", NA),
c3 = c("K", "M", NA, "M))
```

So far I have been using `tidyr::separate`

```
df %>%
separate(c1, into =c("c2", "c3"), sep = "(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])")
```

But this only works for the first three cases. I realize this is because `?<=...` and `?=...` require the presence of the regex. How would one modify this code to capture the cases where the numbers are missing before the letters? Been trying to use the `extract` function too, but without success.

Edit: I suppose one solution is to break this up into

```
df$col2 <- as.numeric(str_extract(df$col1, "[0-9]+"))
df$col3 <- (str_extract(df$col1, "[aA-zZ]+"))
```

But I was curious whether were other ways to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

```
extract(df, c1, into =c("c2", "c3"), "([\\.\\d]*)([a-zA-Z]*)")
#    c2 c3
# 1 5.5  K
# 2   2  M
# 3 3.1   
# 4      M
```

You can use `seperate` simply in this way, but there should be a more elegant method..

```
df %>% separate(c1, into =c("c2", "c3"), sep = "(?=[A-Za-z])")
#    c2   c3
# 1 5.5    K
# 2   2    M
# 3 3.1 <NA>
# 4        M
```

Comment: Thank you! This was great help!

Answer (score 1):

We can use base R `sub` to remove characters and numbers respectively to get different columns.

```
df$c2 <- sub("[A-Za-z]+", "", df$c1)
df$c3 <- sub("\\d*\\.?\\d*", "", df$c1)

df
#    c1  c2 c3
#1 5.5K 5.5  K
#2   2M   2  M
#3  3.1 3.1   
#4    M      M
```

You can remove `c1` column if not needed later by doing `df$c1 <- NULL`.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing something very similar!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `regex` grouping `\1` and `\2`. This is very similar to and adapted from @Ronak Shah's answer but with regex grouping

```r
# data
df <- data.frame(c1 = c("5.5K", "2M", "3.1", "M"))

# keep only numeric
df$c2 <- sub("(\\d*\\.?\\d*)([A-Za-z]*)", "\\1", df$c1)

# keep only alphabets
df$c3 <- sub("(\\d*\\.?\\d*)([A-Za-z]*)", "\\2", df$c1)
df[df == ""] = NA

df
#>     c1   c2   c3
#> 1 5.5K  5.5    K
#> 2   2M    2    M
#> 3  3.1  3.1 <NA>
#> 4    M <NA>    M
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We can use `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df, c1, into = c("c2", "c3"), "^([0-9.]*)([A-Z]*)",
        convert = TRUE, remove = FALSE)
#    c1  c2 c3
#1 5.5K 5.5  K
#2   2M 2.0  M
#3  3.1 3.1   
#4    M  NA  M
```

---

Or with `read.csv` from `base R`

```
read.csv(text= sub("^([0-9.]*)", "\\1,", df$c1), 
   header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, col.names = c("c2", "c3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the package *unglue* :

```r
df <- data.frame(c1 = c("5.5K", "2M", "3.1", "M"))

library(unglue)
unglue_unnest(df, c1, "{c2}{c3=\\D*}", convert = TRUE)
#>    c2 c3
#> 1 5.5  K
#> 2 2.0  M
#> 3 3.1   
#> 4  NA  M
```